# Find number of ad clicks in each hour

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm very new to spark and learning it.I ran into a wall where i want to find number of clicks in each hour. Given this table:
[adclicks_schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Larw.png)

So far i converted the timestamp like this:

```
timestamp_only = adclicks.selectExpr(["to_timestamp(timestamp) as timestamp"])

click_count_by_hour = adclicks.select("timestamp")

click_count_by_hours.show(24)
```

And i'm stuck, what should i do next? Is there any spark sql functions that i can use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract `hour` from timestamp using **hour** (or) **date_format** in built functions.

- groupBy on `hour` and `count` number of records.

---

**`Example:`**

```
#sample data
df.show()
#+-------------------+
#|          timestamp|
#+-------------------+
#|2019-10-01 12:22:34|
#|2019-10-01 13:22:34|
#+-------------------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn("hour",hour(col("timestamp"))).\
groupBy("hour").\
agg(count("*").alias("count")).\
show()
#+----+-----+
#|hour|count|
#+----+-----+
#|  12|    1|
#|  13|    1|
#+----+-----+

#using date_format function

df.withColumn("hour",date_format(col("timestamp").cast("timestamp"),"yyyy-MM-dd HH")).\
groupBy("hour").\
agg(count("*").alias("count")).\
show()
#+-------------+-----+
#|         hour|count|
#+-------------+-----+
#|2019-10-01 13|    1|
#|2019-10-01 12|    1|
#+-------------+-----+
```

Comment: Wow very simple, the the function withColumn with the first parameter, is that the alias you set up for timestamp?

Comment: @AlvisLuu, Not an alias but we are creating new column called `hour` and using it in `groupBy`!